# Add fingerprint to old paperclip attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment, fingerprint

I use paperclip for the attachments on my models. I've recently added  a fingerprint to the attachments, it works fine with the new attachments but it ws not added to the old ones, because of this I'm having trouble reprocessing attachments to add a new style, because paperclip tries to find the attachments with fingerprint and not all the attachments have one.

Is there a way to add the fingerprint to the old attachments?

This is the error I'm getting from the reprocessing on the old attachments:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/paperclip-reprocess20140422-1036-nl9gxk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manually try and examine the error several times I found that the problem is not that the attachment had no fingerprint. The problem was that the fingerprint was nil. For some reason paperclip does not handle this case.

I manually gave every object an empty string as a fingerprint through the database (this saved me from renaming the file on disk) and then reprocess every one of theme.

That solved it!

Answer (score 1):

[edit]
Have you tried?

```
$ rake paperclip:refresh class=Model_Name_Goes_Here
```

[/edit]

if you don't have too many images. simplest way, I can think of is:

```
Dir.foreach('/path/to/dir/that/contains/old/images') do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..'
  file = File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), item)
  thing.image = file
  thing.save
end
```

you can run this script, using runner:

```
$ rails runner /path/to/script
```

Does something like this work for you?

Comment: I have a lor of images. Paperclip doesn't have a function or something like that?

Comment: they do have a rake task which I haven't used as I am on carrierwave now. Updated my answer with that. see if that helps

Comment: Interesting. can you post steps to reproduce this via sample app on github?

Comment: Found a solution. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Glad  that you were able to figure it out.